# urlrewrite and search engines

Tags: search-engines, url-rewriting

I have a urlrewrite that rewrites my urls like

```
mypage.aspx?id=123&title=mytitle
```

into

```
...page/mytitle/123/
```

I'm trying to understand what are the pros / cons if any of having it like

```
...page/mytitle/123/
```

instead of

```
...page/123/mytitle/
```

Does it make any difference for search engines and is there anything i'm doing wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pick one. (Read: you're putting too much thought into this.)
They're not different enough to matter, and whatever benefit one *might* have over the other isn't going to be enough to offset the time spent debating.

I would actually ask why you're retaining the `id` value at all.
It doesn't serve any apparent purpose, and if you end up migrating to another CMS/whatever in the future, you may end up with new ID values, resulting in new URLs, broken links, waiting to get re-indexed, etc.

Comment: i'm not indexing ids with the titles.... i'm using the iis7 urlrewrite feature so i have to retain those. I'm not that familiar with apache. From what i understand i can index them with apache but not with iis7 urlrewrite